# Are managed properties already set to default values when -awakeFromFetch is called?

Tags: iphone, core-data

Are managed properties already set to default values when -awakeFromFetch is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awakeFromFetch assumes, the object has already been inserted before, so no the object properties will not be set to default values.

if you meant awakeFromInsert, yes all properties have their modeled default values before invocation.